# Error after Upgrading Joomla 2.5 to joomla 3.4.4

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5

Please see the image, I got the error just shortly after   I upgraded Joomla 2.5 website to Joomla 3.4.4

[image]

This will really be a great help for me anyone can help.

Thank you

Comment: There is no image in your question. Please check again.

Comment: What upgrade process did you follow? What steps?

Comment: Why upgraded to J3.4.4 - when the 3.4.8 is out that also deals with 2 high priority security issues. Regarding the error itself, I would suggest to re-try upgrading using the Joomla Update component. So, grab a new backup of your J2.5. install it locally or at the dev server you are doing your upgrades/development and run again the update. Make sure it will make it to the end of the process. You may also want to disable any excessive plugins and modules before the upgrade.

Comment: Agreed with @FFrewin, especially abaout disabling any excessive plugins and modules. From the SQL Error you provided, it is almost impossible to find the problem, but first thing one notices are table names like 'ytht_content_frontpage' and 'ytht_contact_details', which are not part or core Joomla, hence they are probably part of some extension, and most likely source of the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have some extensions that are not compatible with Joomla 3.x.

If you can still log in to the back-end, try disabling or removing these to see if it helps.

Answer (score 6):

This error generally arises because of mismatch in columns present in Joomla3x and Joomla2.5 tables. To fix this, follow the following steps:

1) If you can access administrator section, then click on the Extension Manager > Database tab > Click **Fix** button.

2) If you cannot access the Database view in admin, then achieve the above step by entering in the URL: 
`websiteurl/administrator/index.php?option=com_installer&task=database.fix`

--This will fix all the database warnings and errors.

If this also doesn't work for you then try updating from scratch.

Hope this helps.